How to apply disable-output-escaping='yes' to some entity references (&gt; and &lt;) and exclude for &amp;
I have citation text within span. The markup string has > and < and &. When I transform that citation text I am using disable-output-escaping='yes'. It is working good for < and >. But I need to exclude this for &. Because I will use the output as an input for another xslt transformation.
This is given text:
<xsl:variable name="text" select="'&lt;span&gt;some text &amp; &lt;span&gt;'"/>

I tried with this code:
<xsl:value-of select="$text" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

What I am getting now:
<span>some text & <span>

What I am expecting:
<span>some text &amp; <span>


Can  you fix the input string? It should be <xsl:variable name="text" select="'&lt;span&gt;some text &amp;amp; &lt;/span&gt;'"/> and then you can just use parse-xml e.g. <xsl:sequence select="parse-xml($text)"/>. <span>some text &amp; <span> is not parseable as XML as you have no closing </span>.

Try to wean yourself off disable-output-escaping, it's a terrible hack with many limitations, and you've discovered one of them.
The right answer here is to parse the embedded XML with an XML parser (using the parse-xml() function in XSLT 3.0, or a vendor-specific extension function in earlier releases), and then to process the parsed XML as a node tree.
However, as Martin points out in his comment, the problem is that your embedded XML isn't well-formed. What your attribute contains is the escaped form of the ill-formed XML <span>some text & <span>. Turning ill-formed XML into well-formed XML is a black art, and is best avoided. You should design your processes so that ill-formed XML can never enter the system, rather than trying to repair it after the event.

What would be the ideal alternative for disable-output-escaping?

Depends on the problem you are trying to solve. If you're trying to process "escaped embedded XML" then the ideal solution is to parse it, as I suggested. The only reason that doesn't work in this case is that you actually have "escaped embedded non-XML".
